# Shopify draft order create generate error 'must correspond to that calculated from the value'

Tags: shopify

I am creating a draft order on Shopify with discount, Its return error like 'must correspond to that calculated from the value'.

I am calculating discount as following:

$amount is the total amount (78.99) of order and $rate (30) is a value of discount percentage.

```
$discount = $amount * ( $rate / 100);
$discount = $discount * pow(10, 2);
$discount = floatval($discount);
$discount = $discount / pow(10, 2);
$new_discount_amt = round($discount, 2);
```

Here, my total is 78.99 and I want to apply a 30% discount on that.
so the final discount amount is 23.7

```
$applied_discount = array(
                "title" => "RCT Reorder Discount",
                "description" => "Description",
                "value" => "30",
                "value_type" => "percentage",
                "amount" => $new_discount_amt
            );
```

Shopify return

```
{"errors":{"applied_discount.amount":["must correspond to that calculated from the value"]}}
```

What's wrong with this calculation?
What is the right method to calculate discount in Shopify?

Answer (score 1):

That looks roughly ok. Remember though that the amount is in cents if you are using a decimal based  currency.

the following works in production in a node.js app:

```
var discount = 0.33;
var qty = parseInt(row.qty,10);
var rate = v.price * discount; //discount amount in cents
var line = {
    variant_id: v.id,
    quantity:qty,
    description: row.description,
    applied_discount:{
        title:'Wholesale Discount',
        value_type:'percentage',
        value:(100*discount),
        amount: Math.floor(100* qty * rate)/100
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks for your time but you are using 'qty' in calculation means you are giving discount on product amount But I am giving discount on total amount of cart.
I also tried with floor function instead round function but same problem occur.

Comment: Sorry. I’m away from my code for a week. I have an example of a body level discount and IIRC it’s almost the same

Comment: This answer made me realize that I have to multiply the `value` with `quantity` and store that in `amount`.